# Ruby issue using Object.send(:remove_const, 'MyClass')

Tags: ruby, rspec

I want to "reinitialize" my `User` class, so i have a fresh state in each of my RSpec examples. I tried calling `remove_const`:

```
before(:each) do
  Object.send(:remove_const, 'User')
  load 'user.rb'
end

describe 'initializer' do
  it 'creates an user' do
    user = User.new("jules", "jules@gg.k")
    expect(user.class).to eq(User)
  end

  it 'saves @email as instance variable' do
    email = "jules@gg.com"
    user = User.new("jules", email)
    expect(user.email).to eq(email)
  end

  # ...
end
```

but it returns:

```
NameError: constant Object::User not defined
```

My `User` class looks like this:

```
class User
  attr_accessor :name, :email
  @@user_list = []
  @@user_count = 0

  def self.user_count
    @@user_count
  end

  def self.all
    @@user_list
  end

  def initialize(name, email)
    @email = email
    @name = name
    @@user_count += 1
    @@user_list << self
  end
end
```

Comment: Show your `'user.rb'` (class declaration at least.)

Comment: _"when I remove it the spec is correctly executed"_ – so why don't you remove it?

Comment: because I want variables instanced in a bloc of the spec file to be reinitialized in other blocs, but I think i understanded wrong the send method.

Comment: first of all thank, you for the time you spend on my issue. I'm unfortunately don't know where i could put my entire code but in an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two options:

1. only remove the constant if it is actually defined:

   ```
   if Object.const_defined?(:User)
     Object.send(:remove_const, :User)
     load 'user.rb' # <- you may have to adjust the path
   end
   ```
2. add a class method to `User` to clear your in-memory user "database":

   ```
   class User
     def self.clear
       @@user_list = []
       @@user_count = 0            
     end
   end
   ```

   and call that instead:

   ```
   before(:each) do
     User.clear
   end
   ```

I'd go with option #2.

Comment: Thank you a lot, the second option solved my problem. I now have to understand const_defined? and send methods by reading the ruby doc.

Answer (score -1):

```
require_relative '../lib/user'

describe User do

    before(:each) do
            Object.send(:remove_const, 'User')
            load 'user'
    end 

    describe 'initializer' do

        it 'creates an user' do
            user = User.new("jules", "jules@gg.k")
            expect(user.class).to eq(User)
        end

        it 'saves @email as instance variable' do
            email = "jules@gg.com"
            user = User.new("jules", email)
            expect(user.email).to eq(email)
        end

        it 'adds one to the @@user_count global variable' do
            count = User.user_count
            user = User.new("jules", "email@email.email")
            expect(User.user_count).to eq(count+1)
        end

    end

    describe 'classe method' do

        describe 'all' do
            it 'should return a list of names of all users' do
                user1 = User.new("jacques", "jacky@chan.fr")
                user2 = User.new("phil", "ph@il.ipe")
                expect(User.all.map! {|k| k.name}).to eq(["jacques", "phil"])
            end
        end

        describe 'find_by_email' do
            it 'should return return a name if user exists and nil otherwise' do
                user1 = User.new("jacques", "jacky@chan.fr")
        user2 = User.new("phil", "ph@il.ipe")
                expect(User.find_by_email("jacky@chan.fr")).to eq("jacques")
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: This is not an answer. There's an _edit_ button under your question so you can add additional information.